# How to create multiple csv file in a multiple folders

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a function that generates multiple CSV files with the current date stamp.
but I need to store that CSV file in a specific folder with a different timestamp.

I want to store those number of folders in some location.

for example:
First I need to create folders.
then in each folder, I need to store generated csv files

This is my code for creating multiple days but it didn't create the CSV file under that created folder:

```py
import os
import csv
from datetime import datetime

sequenc_date = ['20210311', '20210312', '20210313', '20210314', '20210315', '20210316', '20210317']
path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
data1 = ["csvfiles_data"]
for folder in sequenc_date:
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, folder))
    with open("output_file_{}-{}.csv".format(datetime.now().replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),datetime.now().replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")), 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data1)
```

Comment: Where you have written `with open("output_file_{}-{}.csv"` etc., what folder do you think you are telling it to put that new file into? Why? How?

Comment: You are not creating any new folders in this code, you should list all the paths location you want to create new folders and then create new a new folder for an example with `os.mkdir(path)` and then create a file in that particular folder.

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas  my code will create 7 folders which is stored in the "sequence_day"

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full path or the relative path to the CSV file, otherwise, python just assumes it to be in the current working directory.

```
with open("./{}/output_file_{}-{}.csv".format(folder, datetime.now().replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),datetime.now().replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00).strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")), 'w') as f:
```